Combinatorics - 6 computers in network
Suppose we plan to put six distinct computers in a network as shown in the following figure. The lines show which computers can communicate directly
with which others. Consider two ways of assigning computers to the
nodes of the network diﬀerent if there are two computers that commu-
nicate directly in one assignment and that don’t communicate directly
in the other. In how many diﬀerent ways can we assign computers to
the network?

The answer is 6!/48 by applying quotient principle.
How do we get the size of each block 48?
Thanks!

Notice that opposite computers can be swapped without changing the assignment.

Assignments can be differentiated by which computers don't directly connect.  Each computer connects to 4 of the 5 others.
So, for computer-1, there are $~5~$ choices for which computer it does not connect to.  Reserve the factor of $~5,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality that [computer-1::computer-2] do not connect.
Then, there are $~3~$ choices for which computer does not connect with computer-3.
So, the number of different assigments is $~5 \times 3 = 15.$
So, the problem is reduced to reverse-engineering the
$~\dfrac{6!}{48}~$ analysis.
One plausible approach is as follows:
In the posted diagram, which has $~6~$ nodes, there are $~6!~$ ways of assigning the $~6~$ computers to the various nodes.
The question is, in general, what is the degree of overcounting.  Divide up the cross vertices (that do not connect with each other) into three pairs.  For a specific assignment, the 6 computers can be assigned into the three pairs of non-connecting computers, and then each of these pairs can be assigned one of the pairs of cross vertices in $~3!~$ ways.
Then, with each of the 3 pairs assigned to one of the pairs of cross vertices, each specific computer pair can be permuted in $~2!~$ ways among the two nodes that comprise a specific pair of cross vertices.
So, you end up with an overcounting-scalar of $~3! \times (2!)^3 = 48,~$ which is one way of reverse-engineering the $~\dfrac{6!}{48}~$ computation.
